# Using log4net to log everthing in app console

Tags: logging, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender, log4net-filter

Is it possible to configure log4net in config File to  catch and trace every action or error in runtime, without programmatically add logging messages in the Code ?
Im using .net core console application.

Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <log4net>
        <appender name="console" type="log4net.Appender.ManagedColoredConsoleAppender">
            <mapping>
                <level value="INFO" />
                <forecolor value="Green" />
            </mapping>
            <mapping>
                <level value="WARN" />
                <forecolor value="Yellow" />
            </mapping>
            <mapping>
                <level value="ERROR" />
                <forecolor value="Red" />
            </mapping>
            <mapping>
                <level value="DEBUG" />
                <forecolor value="Blue" />
            </mapping>
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger.%method[%line] - %message%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <appender name="file" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <file value="C:\LOGS\Trace.log" />
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <rollingStyle value="Size" />
            <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
            <maximumFileSize value="25MB" />
            <staticLogFileName value="true" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger.%method[%line] - %message%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <appender name="EventLogAppender" type="Log4Net.Appenders.NetCore.EventLogAppender,Log4Net.Appenders.NetCore">
            <applicationName value="Log4NetSample.ConsoleApp.exe" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
        
        <root>
            <level value="debug" />
            <appender-ref ref="console" />
            <appender-ref ref="file" />
            <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender" />
        </root>
    </log4net>

</configuration>
```

Comment: So do you want to log the output of `Console.WriteLine`? I don’t really understand what you’re asking. Can you add some examples into your question?

Comment: @stuartd thank you for response, I update it my question